# Php message form charset not works

Tags: php

Here is my code, i tried to set char coding to utf-8 but it isnt work.
In the éáőí characters looks like ĂŠ.
In html the charset is utf-8 and works, i think the php is the wrong.
Thanks for help!

PHP

```
<?php
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: YourWebsite.com'; 
    $to = 'anything@website.com'; 
    $subject = 'Email Inquiry';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
?>

<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from, $headers)) { 
        echo '<p>Thank you for your email!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: did you try changing page encoding with an editor?

Comment: The problem is in the sent email, In the homepage the characters looks like fine, the received message contains other characters.

Comment: I can suggest you to use PHPMailer, which is more effective on controlling these values.